# How to call multiple completablefuture concurrently after main completable future completed

Tags: java-8, completable-future

How to enhance function below, where getB, getC, getD have dependency with A, and required to wait A to complete before call.
However i wish to call B C D concurrently after A completed.

Thankyou for all the helps

note: all dbService return a completableFuture

```
CompletableFuture<List<A>> a= dbService.getA(request);
a.thenApply(a-> {
                try {
                    return dbService.getB(a);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .thenAccept (result->{
                //do something with B
            });

a.thenApply(a-> {
                try {
                    return dbService.getC(a);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .thenAccept (result->{
                //do something with C
            });

a.thenApply(a-> {
                try {
                    return dbService.getD(a);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .thenAccept (result->{
                //do something with D
            });
```

Comment: Use `thenApplyAsync`?

Comment: U means combining all with applyAsync ? if so, how i can repass in parameters A

Comment: What do you mean? Just replace all three `thenApply` with `thenApplyAsync`.

Comment: i means is there anyway to combine all three in one function ? thanks

Comment: You said, you want B, C, and D to run concurrently. So no, you can’t have that and these concurrently running invocations in one function. There’s no sense in that either. If you want to simplify the code, fix the dbService method to not throw `InterruptedException`, as it is a contradiction to return an object representing an *asynchronous* operation, but declare to throw an exception indicating a wait operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the returns of B, C, D then:

```
CompletionStage<List<A>> aFuture = dbService.getA(request);
aFuture.whenCompleteAsync((a, ex) -> {
    if (ex != null) {
        dbService.getB(a);
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
aFuture.whenCompleteAsync((a, ex) -> {
    if (ex != null) {
        dbService.getC(a);
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
aFuture.whenCompleteAsync((a, ex) -> {
    if (ex != null) {
        dbService.getD(a);
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Your program will return to the main event loop as soon as `dbService.getA(request)` kicks off, *i.e.* before it even completes. And when that *does* complete, each of the 3 blocks execute (due to having been queued by `whenComplete`) on different threads (than main and each other, due to the `Async`).

If you *do* want to do something with the returns of B, C, and D, then:

```
CompletionStage<List<A>> aFuture = dbService.getA(request);

CompletionStage<B> bFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getB(a);
});
CompletionStage<C> cFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getC(a);
});
CompletionStage<D> dFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getD(a);
});

CompletionStage<Something> sFuture = bFuture.thenCompose(b -> {
    cFuture.thenCompose(c -> {
        dFuture.thenApply(d -> {
            // do something with b, c, d
            return new Something();
        });
    });
});
```

You can shorten this using `thenCombine`, which is like a `thenApply` that waits on 2 futures:

```
CompletionStage<List<A>> aFuture = dbService.getA(request);

CompletionStage<B> bFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getB(a);
});
CompletionStage<C> cFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getC(a);
});
CompletionStage<D> dFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getD(a);
});

CompletionStage<Something> sFuture = bFuture.thenCompose(b -> {
    cFuture.thenCombine(dFuture, (c, d) -> {
        // do something with b, c, d
        return new Something();
    });
});
```

To extend this to any number of concurrent stages, I like to use [Spotify's CompletableFutures package](https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures) like this:

```
CompletionStage<List<A>> aFuture = dbService.getA(request);

CompletionStage<B> bFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getB(a);
});
CompletionStage<C> cFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getC(a);
});
CompletionStage<D> dFuture = aFuture.thenApplyAsync(a -> {
    return dbService.getD(a);
});

CompletionStage<Something> sFuture = CompletableFutures.combine((bFuture, cFuture, dFuture) -> {
    // do something with b, c, d
    return new Something();
}
```